# How is the loss between actual and predicted labels being calculated?

Tags: tensorflow

Quoting from [this example](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google-research/bert/blob/master/predicting_movie_reviews_with_bert_on_tf_hub.ipynb) of Predicting movie review with BERT and Tensorflow,

```
with tf.variable_scope("loss"):
        # Dropout helps prevent overfitting
        output_layer = tf.nn.dropout(output_layer, keep_prob=0.9)

        logits = tf.matmul(output_layer, output_weights, transpose_b=True)
        logits = tf.nn.bias_add(logits, output_bias)
        log_probs = tf.nn.log_softmax(logits, axis=-1)

        # Convert labels into one-hot encoding
        one_hot_labels = tf.one_hot(labels, depth=num_labels, dtype=tf.float32)

        predicted_labels = tf.squeeze(tf.argmax(log_probs, axis=-1, output_type=tf.int32))
        # If we're predicting, we want predicted labels and the probabiltiies.
        if is_predicting:
            return (predicted_labels, log_probs)

        # If we're train/eval, compute loss between predicted and actual label
        per_example_loss = -tf.reduce_sum(one_hot_labels * log_probs, axis=-1)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(per_example_loss)
        return (loss, predicted_labels, log_probs)
```

How is the loss between actual and predicted labels being calculated?

The above example id for multi-class, single-label setting. If I want to calculate the `loss` for a multi-class, multi-label problem, how can I do the necessary computation in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

The per example loss is calculated by multiplying the one hot encoded result which will be 1 for the true class and 0 for the others with the softmax output which outputs a probability for each class.
Essentially we are picking the prediction for the relevant class.
In the next step we reduce the negative of this value which essentially is maximizing the probability of the class of interest.

The above approach should work fine for multi label as well. However using sigmoid instead of softmax to arrive at the probabilities for the multiple classes doesn't clip probabilities of other classes

Comment: How can I use sigmoid for the multi-label case? And in that case, `tf.argmax` will no longer work, right?

Comment: In multi-label  we would not use argmax because it will provide only 1 class as the predicted class.

Comment: Instead we could use a threshold in like 0.5 for each class and hence would need sigmoid.

Comment: for multi-class, you don't use sigmoid, you use softmax.